# Where to check Apollo server express GraphQL cache?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using Apollo Sever Express to build a GraphQL endpoint. As per their documentations, I've added the @cacheControl, the directives in my typeDefs schema. But I'm not sure if it's working, how can I validate or test this situation? I run the server at localhost:3000/graphql (GraphQL ide is opened).

Code-

```
type Post {
 id: ID!
 title: String
 votes: Int @cacheControl(maxAge: 30)
}
```

Also tried the dynamic one as well in resolvers, but how/where should I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Min Yoongi
I too used `RestDataSource` and I set the headers like this:

```
getData(headers){
  return this.get("endpoint", "params block", {
    headers: headers
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're after. If you are trying to utilize HTTP caching, you should look at the network calls and see if it sets the `cache-control` response header. If you want the entire query to be cached, I would simply `console.log` inside a resolver to see if it is executing.

Comment: How can set headers for caching underlying REST API?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built in. I know Apollos DataSource classes use underlying headers to cache internally, but I don't think that will forward the headers.

I would read the headers from the REST response, and programmatically set the cache control in apollo.

Comment: Yes @peternyc, I tried RESTDataSource to set headers but it didn't help. Can you provide code reference for the second point that you mentioned?